Had some problems checking in with an eVisa. Why did it happen and how can I prevent it from happening again?
I applied for an Australian eVisitor visa on December 19th, 2023 holding a UK passport.
I was approved within 10 minutes. My actual date of travel was on the 27th of March, 2024. I checked in with my partner in Phuket airport. She checked in fine, but the clerks were unable to check me in. Glancing at the screen, there was something along the lines of “Government APPS warning issued for passport” next to my security clearance field.
The clerk called her supervisor and they spent some time on the phone, presumably with the Australian Border Operations Centre (although they said it was embassy, who knows). I was eventually let through, but naturally this freaked me out, and I spent a good chunk of time reading up on the Australian Advanced Passenger Processing System and what could’ve happened there. I did not experience any extra scrutiny during the trip and went through e-gates without problem.
I'm still a bit unclear on the details of why it could’ve happened (considering all my details and visa were correct) and most importantly, whether it will happen again in another airport with a less patient or knowledgable clerk. I plan on travelling to/from Australia a couple of times.
Could anyone shed some light on the most plausible scenario behind my check-in difficulties and whether it might bite me again? Do I need to take any preventative action? Thank you kindly.


Could anyone shed some light on the most plausible scenario behind my check-in difficulties

Poorly programmed IT system with a high false positive rate for whatever fraud detection systems they have running in the background. Visa systems are somewhat mercurial by nature so the exact reason would be hard to confirm. But given your experience it’s definitely not a problem with your passport or you as a person.

Do I need to take any preventative action?

No, nor is there any action you could possibly take. I’ve had similar experiences with various immigration systems around the world and unfortunately nothing can ever be done. Relax and enjoy your next trip.
